# Scrollable div container managed by internal-links, but wihout using iframe?

Tags: html, css, css-position, scrollable

I want to have a "movable" (i mean scrollable, but without visible scrollbars) `div` which will show content by passing it's `div` in address bar. Example : **localhost/page/index.html#third** will show me `#third` div in `#window-container` at the page:

**I presented it on this image:**
[image]

I don't want to use `iframe` because I had problem with managing DOM elements between parent `window` and `iframe` (by `postMessage()` method). I'd rather use `position: fixed`, but how to make this `div` at the center scrollable by `internal link`'s, like at the image?

Everything in `div` with "some text" paragraphs should be visible **only** in the `#window-container` `div`, which will be some kind of window where user can see content of that scrollable div.

Comment: give css: overflow: scroll or auto

Comment: On which element: `#window-container` or the center div which i want to be scrollable?

Comment: @NabeelKhan Ok it works but i want it to be scrolled only when i pass proper `id` of element, not all the time with mouse wheel.

Comment: Use  Internal links html ... `<a href="#yourid">Link</a>`

Comment: how do you want to show the "active" div? Do you want all other divs to get `display:none` or do you want the parent to "scroll" the position to the "active" div (i.e.: change of top offset) BTW You will never JavaScript to detect hash links. are you ok with jQuery? Also, please provide your HTML/CSS code, ideally a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks to @NabeelKhan comment + `overflow-y: hidden;`